# Custom axis labels for Core Plot

Tags: charts, core-plot, labeling

I spent more than a week trying to have custom axis label for Core Plot, without success. I read many tutorials and examples on SO, and tried to replicate it in my project, but no success. Please help.

This is the code I have:

```
// Create an CPXYGraph and host it inside the view
CPTTheme *theme = [CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTPlainWhiteTheme];
CPTXYGraph *graph = (CPTXYGraph *)[theme newGraph];
hostView.hostedGraph = graph;

graph.paddingTop = 10.0;
graph.paddingLeft = 10.0;
graph.paddingRight = 10.0;
graph.paddingBottom = 10.0;

[graph.plotAreaFrame setPaddingTop:10.0f];
[graph.plotAreaFrame setPaddingLeft:55.0f];
[graph.plotAreaFrame setPaddingRight:10.0f];
[graph.plotAreaFrame setPaddingBottom:35.0f];

// Set up Plot Space
CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
plotSpace.allowsUserInteraction = YES;
plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromInteger(800)
                                               length:CPTDecimalFromInteger(400)];
plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(7000)
                                               length:CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(1000)];

// Set up Axes
CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)graph.axisSet;

CPTXYAxis *x = axisSet.xAxis;
x.majorIntervalLength = CPTDecimalFromInteger(60);
x.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromInteger(7000);
x.minorTicksPerInterval = 3;
x.borderWidth = 0;
x.majorTickLength = 5.0f;
x.minorTickLength = 2.0f;
x.axisLineCapMax = [CPTLineCap openArrowPlotLineCap];
x.axisLineCapMax.size = CGSizeMake(8, 10);

x.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic;

NSMutableSet *xLabels = [NSMutableSet setWithCapacity:[self.arrXValues count]];
NSMutableSet *xLocations = [NSMutableSet setWithCapacity:[self.arrXValues count]];

CGFloat location = 0.0;
for (NSString *string in self.arrXValues) {
    CPTAxisLabel *label = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText:string  textStyle:x.labelTextStyle];
    location++;
    label.tickLocation = CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(location);
    label.offset = x.titleOffset + x.majorTickLength;
    if (label) {
        [xLabels addObject:label];
        [xLocations addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:location]];
    }
}
x.axisLabels = xLabels;
x.majorTickLocations = xLocations;

CPTXYAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;
y.majorIntervalLength = CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(250);
y.minorTicksPerInterval = 5;
y.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromInteger(800);
y.majorTickLength = 5.0f;
y.minorTickLength = 2.0f;
y.axisLineCapMax = [CPTLineCap openArrowPlotLineCap];
y.axisLineCapMax.size = CGSizeMake(8, 10);

// Set up the chart
CPTScatterPlot *linePlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];
linePlot.identifier = @"AAPL";
CPTMutableLineStyle *lineStyle = [linePlot.dataLineStyle mutableCopy];
lineStyle.lineWidth = 2.f;
lineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor blueColor];
linePlot.dataLineStyle = lineStyle;

linePlot.dataSource = self;
[graph addPlot:linePlot];
```

And this is my data structure:

```
self.arrXValues = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"900", @"930", @"1000", @"1010", @"1020", @"1030", @"1040", @"1050", @"1100", @"1130", nil];
self.arrYValues = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"7600", @"7460", @"7700", @"7720", @"7680", @"7700", @"7720", @"7720", @"7680", @"7700", nil];
```

If I turn labelingPolicy to CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic, it will show the default labels, but at least affirms that the labels are not hidden by something else. Unfortunately, I don't have enough reputations to post images.

Please help spot the mistake, there must something silly out there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're positioning the custom labels outside the visible plot range. The `xRange` covers values between 800 and 1,200 (`length` of 400). The labels are at 1, 2, 3, etc. Use the label value as the `tickLocation`:

```
label.tickLocation = CPTDecimalFromString(string);
[xLocations addObject:string];
```

Comment: @hsh @Eric Its not working for me x axis labels are showing values from `xLocations` not from xLabels titles.

Comment: @MuhammadYawarAli This question is over a year old. Please ask a new question with details of your situation and we can help. Be sure to use the `core-plot` tag on the question.

Comment: @Eric http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36614204/change-tick-labels-for-coreplot-graph