# Change Tick Labels for Coreplot Graph

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, core-plot

I am using `coreplot` for graphs in my mac application & its working fine. I have a requirement to show `custom labels` along the axis for ticks like :

I have a graph for power values against time : `Power values -> Y-Axis` & `Time -> X-Axis`.

`I want to draw graph for Time seconds values but show fixed intervals ticks of minutes along x-axis for which i figured that i should use custom labels but its not happening for me.`

Code for custom labels is :

```
  let graph = CPTXYGraph()

  plots[0].identifier = PlotType.target.rawValue
  plots[1].identifier = PlotType.user.rawValue

  for plot in plots {
     plot.dataSource = self
     plot.delegate = self
     graph.addPlot(plot)
  }

  if let plotArea = graph.plotAreaFrame {
     plotArea.borderLineStyle = nil
     plotArea.paddingLeft = 25.0
     plotArea.paddingBottom = 20.0
     plotArea.paddingRight = 10.0
     plotArea.paddingTop = 20.0
  }

  guard let axisSet = graph.axisSet else { return }

  let xAxis = axisSet.axes?[0]
  var xLabels = [CPTAxisLabel]()
  var xLocations = [NSNumber]()

  let doubleSecs = Double(activity.durationSeconds)
  let labels = [0.0, doubleSecs * 0.25, doubleSecs * 0.50, doubleSecs * 0.75, doubleSecs]
  for label in labels {
     let xLabel = CPTAxisLabel(text: "\(label/60)", textStyle: axisTextStyle)
     xLabel.tickLocation = NSNumber(double: label)
     xLocations.append(NSNumber(double: label))
     xLabels.append(xLabel)
  }
  xAxis?.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicy.LocationsProvided
  xAxis?.labelFormatter = axisFormatter
  xAxis?.axisLabels = Set(xLabels)
  xAxis?.majorTickLocations = Set(xLocations)

  chartView.hostedGraph = graph
```

With above code it is drawing graph & along x-axis it is dividing time in 4 equal portions & showing labels, everything is good.

> `I want to show labels along x-axis as minutes and remaining drawing
>   is ok.`
>
> I tried with this : `let xLabel = CPTAxisLabel(text: "\(label/60)",
>   textStyle: axisTextStyle())` but labels are not changing no effect.
>
> Also tried to change `tickLocation` like : `xLabel.tickLocation =
>   NSNumber(double: label/60)` No effect
>
> With changing `majorTickLocations` like :
>   `xLocations.append(NSNumber(double: label/60))` it behaving weird and
>   all x-axis labels are messed.

I tried to follow this example : [StackOverFlow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27715864/custom-axis-labels-for-core-plot/27722786?noredirect=1#comment60819262_27722786)

**Can anyone guide whats going wrong [Remember I am using Swift] ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself by doing it like :

```
  let xAxis = axisSet.axes?[0]
  xAxis?.majorIntervalLength = activity.durationSeconds / 60 / 4
  xAxis?.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicy.FixedInterval
```

Now labels are coming as required.

Answer (score 0):

The `.LocationsProvided` labeling policy uses the `labelFormatter` to create labels from the tick locations automatically. If you want to use custom labels, use the `.None` labeling policy instead.

Comment: I tried with `.None` then it is not showing any labels at all.

Comment: You may need to adjust the `offset` off each label. They're probably outside the visible part of the graph.